# Create drop down list in the create return dump

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've create MVC5 Application and I want in the create use drop down list for server attribute
and I get dump (error is:"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.") when I run it how should I do that right?

I try with

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SystemType, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">

                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SystemType, Model.SystemType)
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User)
        </div>
    </div>
```

in the model class I have the following code

public class Amta
    {

```
    public string User { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SystemType
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem {Value = "D", Text = "Dev"},
                new SelectListItem {Value = "p", Text = "Production"}
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Model.Server needs to be a SelectList

Comment: What is 'Model.Server' ?

Comment: @COLDTOLD - this is wrong since I change with all the test that I done.. I update the post,still not working

Comment: @RKS - wrong ,I update the post still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property to Amta model in order to collect the selected value when the form is posted back.

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedSystemType", Model.SystemType)
```

OR

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSystemType, Model.SystemType)

public class Amta {

    public string User { get; set; }

    public string SelectedSystemType { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SystemType
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem {Value = "D", Text = "Dev"},
                new SelectListItem {Value = "p", Text = "Production"}
            };
        }
    }
}
```

### ## Here is how I Test ##

### Controller

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    return View(new TestModel());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(TestModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

### View

```
@model DemoKendoMvc.Models.TestModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSystemType, Model.SystemType)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

### Model

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string User { get; set; }

    public string SelectedSystemType { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SystemType
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem {Value = "D", Text = "Dev"},
                new SelectListItem {Value = "p", Text = "Production"}
            };
        }
    }
}
```

### Posted Value

[image]

### ## Updated the code asked in Comment ##

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new TestModel());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(TestModel model)
{
    try
    {
        // TODO: Add insert logic here

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

If you use **Create Template** while creating a View, **SelectedSystemType** is created as **EditorFor**. Therefore, you need to change it to **DropDownListFor**.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSystemType, Model.SystemType)
```

Comment: Thanks tim,I was tried both of them and still get the same dump,I afraid that this is because of the second parameter Model.SystemType,any idea?

Comment: its happen even I add                 @if (Model.SystemType != null)
                {
                    @Html.DropDownList("SelectedSystemType", Model.SystemType)
                }

Comment: I dont understand it ,I create new project ,create class and put the property as you write and then create new controller by scaffold and put the code of the drop down in the create operation and its not working. when I put the code in the index cshtml the drop down is working what can be the problem?

Comment: By default, **ASP.Net MVC Template** comes with a lot of extra stuffs. The worst case, you can try with **Empty MVC Template.**

Comment: yes but I need the table since I have addtional properties which bound to sql table...maybe in the create i should use diffrent code for the drop down list? in your program you generate scaffold and put the code in the create or the index ?in the index its working ,I was able to see the drop down but in the create I use the same code and I got dump ...

Comment: Thanks for your support Im stuck with it for a day without able to understand why its working on the index.cshtml and not in the create.cshtml...

Comment: If you time (3 min i checked to create new model e2e)try please to use the model and just generate controller with scaffold and just put the code in the create operation ,and check if you get dump in the drop down list...THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!

Comment: HI Win ,this is what I did (see my question post) and I got the error,did you try with scaffholding and change it in the create and it works for you?

Comment: Maybe the root cause of the problem is that I create the instance of the drop down list in the model,there is a way to do that with enum or  diffrent approch ?if yes can you please provide example?

Comment: `instance of the drop down list in the model` I'm not sure I follow it. `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is a standard approach to create DropDownList, and `public string SelectedSystemType { get; set; }` to get the selected value. I had uploaded the code for **Get** and **Post** Create action yesterday. You should not use **enum** in View Model; it is not a good design practice, because **View** shouldn't need to know about Domain layer.

Comment: Thanks Win :) missed the part of the return (new TestModel()); marked as solved!:( ,just last question the systemType drop value is currently is in the model ,should I put this in somewhere else?

Comment: I'm glad that you figure out. `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SystemType` is the options for DropDownList. It should be only in the View Model; it shouldn't be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Check the overloads for DropDownListFor. I feel you need to use this one.

[DropDownListFor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703462%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

The first expression should be a lambda expression which points to a property which string return type. This will return the selected element of dropdown.

The second expression should be the List which you want to bind with your dropdown.

Check these two things and let me know if its still not working for you.

Here you are using `SystemType` property in lambda expression as well as the list.

Comment: thanks can you please provide example how to put the list there since this is on the model...

Comment: Just as you have defined a property User above SystemType, you need to define one more property which will carry the SelectedValue back during POST. You need to bind this property in lambda expression

Comment: the user is working but here I need drop down list ,can you post the code please which you think should solve the issue?

Comment: Its exactly the way Win has posted in answer.